# Join two dataframes with same column name on the basis of Time Stamp

Tags: r

I have two dataframes with hourly data.

First Data frame is named DENVER as shown below.

| Timestamp | Heating_energy | Lighting_Energy | Total_Energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00 | 2 | 6 | 8 |
| 01/01/2021 01:00 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 01/01/2021 02:00 | 5 | 1 | 6 |

Second Data frame is named CHICAGO as shown below.

| Timestamp | Heating_energy | Lighting_Energy | Total_Energy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 01:00 | 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 01/01/2021 02:00 | 2 | 6 | 8 |

Two data frames have same timestamp. But I want to join them column wise..

| Timestamp | Heating_energy_DENVER | Lighting_Energy_DENVER | Total_Energy_DENVER | Heating_energy_CHICAGO | Lighting_Energy_CHICAGO | Total_Energy_CHICAGO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00 | 2 | 6 | 8 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 01/01/2021 01:00 | 5 | 5 | 10 | 6 | 1 | 7 |
| 01/01/2021 02:00 | 5 | 1 | 6 | 2 | 6 | 8 |

How can I make this work in R? Thank you so much for looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
merge(DENVER,CHICAGO,by="Timestamp",suffixes=c("_DENVER","_CHICAGO"))
```

Comment: Note that you can change the suffix for repeat column names using the `suffixes` argument, which may be desirable here.

Comment: Thanks, @aosmith. I have just edited my code accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much... this is great...